# Turn a bunch of photos into a PDF book, splitting and "fixing" pages

Tags: software-recommendation, preview, ocr

I have a series of images of the pages from a very old reference book that I use all the time. Some are a single page, some facing pages.

On iOS are there apps that will automatically fix-up such images - de-keystone them and split pages and such and turn it into a single PDF.

Is there something similar on the macOS side?

Comment: This would be a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a note, we welcome software recommendation questions here. This is well specified and on topic.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had decent luck using notes on iOS with physical pages to capture documents. The auto detection works pretty darn well, but it is a manual process.

Downsides to this are:

- Uses camera so you’re holding the deceive
- Need to control the lighting and background
- Does not easily take digital input

Positive for this:

- Excellent color / grayscale / black and white processing
- Keystone control
- Decent smart leveling of the contrast
- Can change and edit the processing after the scan is done
- Can export as PDF to files when done
- Can insert, edit and change the scan

On the macOS side, dragging them all into preview and dragging them in order might be more or less of a pain depending on how well organized they are. Hopefully you can find a better prepared copy of that reference book once you estimate the cost to patch together your folder of Humpty Dumpty selfies. Continuity Camera works well if you find it easier to fix things on the Mac.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209037

Comment: On the Mac you can use Apple’s Preview. Create a one page PDF. Open it in Preview. Drag and drop your pictures into the miniture page overview bar (after opening it). For images of facing pages you have to drop them twice and use the crop tool to create subsequent single pages. If you want to automate this I suggest to use ghostscript to create a pdf from multiple images, each representing a single page.

Comment: I should try the preview cropping and rotation again on the new OS with M1 chip. The reason for iOS was it did much of the cropping heavy lifting for me, then I would tune up the PDF in macOS when needed @slartibartfast

Comment: @bmike - when you say "in notes", do you mean the Notes app? Does this do automatic de-keystoning?

Comment: Wow, that is news to me, I've never used Notes in this fashion. Do you mind briefly explaining your process? Do I take the pictures in the Camera app and then transfer them into Notes, or can you do this directly in the Notes app itself? I think the macOS side is clear enough - the images will appear in Notes on the mac through iCloud and then just drag them into Preview to produce the multi-page PDF document - I do this action fairly often already.

Comment: Not sure I can be more clear. You might have to experiment a bit - I use iOS for keystone adjustments as it fits my process better

Answer (score 0):

I use Affinity Publisher on Mac (hopefully on iPad some day) for stuff like this. But you would have to scan & transfer from iPhone or other source. If you're on a newer iPhone & Mac, some of that transfer is automated with Handoff integration I think, but maybe only works with Pages (not sure I only have older stuff).

Comment: I was unfamiliar with this program so I looked it up, but it seems it does not have an import function like this (it is an oft-requested feature)? Perhaps you mean one of the other apps in the package, like Photo?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, "there's more than one way."  What I would do is:

- Open the PDF with [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/)
- Select a photo, and copy to clipboard (⌘-C)
- ⌘-J to get the photo as a new image
- Use one of the **Effect→Unskew (Keystone)** features
- ⌘-0 (Cmd-zero) to get the entire image on screen
- Crop down to the amount of photo desired.
- Do any other edits you want
- ⌘-A ⌘-C (select the entire image and copy to clipboard)
- Select the original PDF page and center the mouse pointer on the original distorted photo
- Paste (⌘-V).  If not positioned right, drag it where you want it.
- Edit out any remnants of the old version sticking out from under the new one.
- **File→Save** the PDF file (automatically goes to the format that was opened.  Or, **Save As** a new file (but check the format on the Save As dialog).